# array for multiple categories

Tags: php, html

I want to make a portfolio with multiple categories.
This is one of five similar category pages…

```
<?php
$pageLabel = 'cat1';
include 'cats-config.php';
?>
```

the cats-config.php…

```
<?php
include 'cats-arrays.php';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allProjects); $i++) {
if (isset($allProjects[$i][$pageLabel])) {
        include ('thumbs/thumb-' . $allProjects[$i] . '.png');
}
}
?>
```

and lastly the cats-arrays.php where I define which project belongs in which category…

```
<?php

//for example

$allProjects = array(
    'project1' => array('cat1', 'cat3', 'cat5'),
    'project2' => array('cat2'),
    'project3' => array('cat3', 'cat4'),
    'project4' => array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat5'),
    'project5' => array('cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5'),
    'project6' => array('cat5'),
    'project7' => array('cat2', 'cat5'),
    'project8' => array('cat1', 'cat3', 'cat4'),
);
?>
```

Doesn't work though, I'm sure something's wrong with the cats-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($allProjects as $projectName => $details)
{
    if(in_array($pageLabel, $details))
       echo $projectName;
}
```

Using foreach will make it much easier to read and clean it up a bit. The 'in_array' will check to see if $pageLabel is inside of $details, which is your array inside each single column in question in $allProjects.

Currently this will return the name of the key inside of $allProjects. From there you can replace the echo with including the images as you were.

Hope that helps!